Networking not working under qemu termux android
I created a virtual machine for windows ARM on qemu-system-aarch64 running under termux android but internet is not working. The virtual machine works fine, Im running on a Samsung A55 5G with sudo permissions. What I'm missing ?
Here is my bash file
#!/bin/bash

qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -M virt,virtualization=true \
  -accel tcg,thread=multi \
  -cpu cortex-a57 \
  -smp 4 \
  -m 4G \
-pflash ./QEMU_EFI.img -pflash ./QEMU_VARS.img \
  -device VGA \
  -device nec-usb-xhci \
  -device usb-kbd \
  -device usb-mouse \
  -nic user,model=virtio \
  -device virtio-blk,drive=system \
  -drive if=none,id=system,format=raw,file=./sys.vhdx \
  -device usb-storage,drive=drivers \
  -drive if=none,id=drivers,readonly=on,format=raw,media=cdrom,file=./virtio-win-0.1.266.iso

And here is a screenshot of VM doing something, I didnt waited for this to boot

